# cmd echo a variable not it's value to a txt

Tags: cmd, echo

I'm know echo "string' >C:\file.txt will print the "string" into the txt file but how do I echo this

```
set Var=10
echo %var% >C:\file.txt
```

output

```
C:\file.txt
10
```

I'm wanting it to output:

```
C:\file.txt
%var%
```

is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo %%var%%>file.txt
```

percent signs are escaped with another percent sign